# Calculate the initial best center AND best initial zoom depending on a list of location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Dear all. I'm pretty new in coding with location, so be nice.

I have a list of location (lat & lng), that could be really anywhere (ie : all in the same city ; one in bangladesh and one in paris...).

When initializing google map, I would like to center on the barycentre on these location.

So this is my first question : **How to calculate a barycentre with location object**

Then, I would also like the initial map do display all the location (markers). So this is a problem of zoom, and is my second question : **How to calculate the zoom in a google map so that all the markers on the map are displayed**

I hope I've been clear. Also, take note that I was meaning barycentre with all points coefed to 1.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To zoom to include a set of results:

```
var locations = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
...
function zoomToViewports(locations) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i in locations) {
    bounds.union(locations[i].geometry.viewport);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Having done that, the barycentre is in the middle of the screen, so if you actually need it's value it's easily calculated [(max(lat)-min(lat)/2,(max(lng)-min(lng)/2]

HTH?

You are welcome to lift the JS from [this page on my website](http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix/offices.htm), which does what you describe

Comment: Yep, that helps. In fact, after writting this post I figured out the keywords for google to find me something. I didn't used bounds.union but extends instead. "extend(point:LatLng) LatLngBounds Extends this bounds to contain the given point." vs "union(other:LatLngBounds) LatLngBounds Extends this bounds to contain the union of this and the given bounds." - I don't get the difference.